# Parsing Exception in shell script

Tags: shell

I am very new to shell script. I have to execute a select statement using shell script. 
The command is

**'SELECT * FROM DB.TABLENAME WHERE prcs_dte >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00.0''**.

It works fine when I am running from DB but when ran as a script I am getting the below exception

**Error, could not parse arguments "00:00:00:0"**

Note : the data type for "prcs_dte" is string and the DB is oracle

if any one phased this issue before, please let me know to resolve this issue

Comment: You need to at least show enough code to let us reproduce the problem ourselves (exactly *how* you're passing that query to your database is a critical detail, and not presently included in the question; for that matter, right now we don't even know which database you're using). See the help center's guidance on creating a [mcve], noting in particular the "complete" and "verifiable" requirements.

Comment: Also, if the issue can be reproduced with a dummy query like `SELECT  '2015-01-01 00:00:00.0'`, I'd suggest doing that in your sample code so we don't need to have any particular schema defined to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I agree with @charles-duffy about some more details. As far I can see, I suggest to check quoting (it seems you havw a single quote inside another external single quote).